# Does anyone store things in http application cache anymore or system.web.cache only?

Tags: asp.net, caching

Does anyone store things in http application cache anymore or system.web.cache only?

Or are they the same thing under the covers?

Answer (score 2):

They are the same thing..from the class System.Web.Caching.Cache

I do use caching in my apps for data that is requested a lot.

My facade layers sets items in cache when they are 1st requested, so on following requests, it checks the cache 1st to see if it's available.

When i'm calling an update or delete statement, I make sure to clear that cache key, so it will be reloaded on th next "SELECT" request.

It saves a lot of trips to the DB.